# Start iphone call from tab bar item

Tags: iphone, call, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

i'm sorry for my english.

I'm trying to develop an app and in one of my tab bar item i want provide the functionality to start a phone call.

I know that is possible to start a call with the following code that i found in another topic:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:12125551212"]];
```

Is possible integrate this method in a "tab bar item"?

Comment: Did you try adding that code to the event handler for the tab bar item? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

and check the viewController.tabBarItem and even return NO to not select view controller and only initiate the call

[UITabBarControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarControllerDelegate%20UITabbarControllerDelegate)

Comment: Thank's for your replay!! i suppose that is the right answer but i'm new in app development and i need to study better the delegate to implement your solution and check the answer... thank's a lot!! Just as possible i'll confirm the answer!!